# Accuracy of /proc/diskstats in Android

Tags: android, linux, performance-testing, benchmarking, disk

I'm trying to measure I/O throughput in Android. I tried a simple test by running Androdbench, and sampling /proc/diskstats for /dev/sda every second. But the results dont match.
Androbench tells me that my phone's storage is capable of a maximum 160MB/s sequential write throughput. But when I diff the "sectors written" field of diskstats I find that the disk writes 500 MB/s at one point. Which doesnt make sense. Here are the two strange samples

207808   53404   19437816    332280  230564  26206   49888720    1100720 0   103030  1433600

207808   53404   19437816    332280  230590  26229   50937672    1100900 0   103210  1433780

These should be block layer results, so to my understanding there should be no cache involved. What am I missing?

Comment: `/proc/diskstat` sector size is probably 512 bytes.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/238033/measuring-total-bytes-written-under-linux for how to find the sector size used for reporting.

Comment: Yeah I know. Using a 512 sector size I'm getting from the above 512 * ( 50937672 -  49888720 ) / 1024 / 1024 = 512 MB/s. 3x high

Comment: Some SSDs have higher burst throughput than sustained, e.g. when the SSD internally has a write buffer using some SLC flash, and it copies from there to slower MLC.  Sustained is limited by the MLC bandwidth when the SLC write buffer fills.  And of course over very short time intervals like you're probably looking at, there's a DRAM buffer inside the SSD (like maybe 64MiB? Maybe much larger), so a burst transfer over the SATA or PCIe connection can go much faster than any flash media.  IDK what's typical for the storage in phones.

Comment: Yeah, but that should also affect the application, androbench in this case. Its measured IO throughput should be similarly higher

Comment: Does Androbench average over a longer period than 1 second?  If not, you might be seeing bursty data while Androbench is averaging that out.  Or maybe something else entirely is going on.  I'm just guessing making wild guesses here.